# Is it possible to make query like: WHERE IF (q.id NOT IN (SELECT ...?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to make query like this? That has some error... 
Query should check if user did answer question with `q.id`.

```
SELECT pictureid,
       id,
       points 
  FROM questions q 
 WHERE IF (q.id NOT IN (SELECT questions_id 
                          FROM history h 
                         WHERE h.users_id = 3))
```

Comment: What database system is that for? IF() is supposed to take three arguments: an expression to evaluate, expresion to return when true, expression to return when false. You only provided first one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT pictureid,id,points 
FROM questions q 
WHERE q.id NOT IN (
    SELECT questions_id 
    FROM history  
    WHERE users_id = 3)
```

Comment: Add AND questions_id IS NOT NULL to the subquery otherwise if there is a null it won't be correct, that is why I prefer EXISTS and NOT EXISTS

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
 SELECT pictureid,id,points 
 FROM questions q 
 WHERE q.id not in 
  (SELECT questions_id FROM history h WHERE h.users_id = 3);
```

Comment: I repeated "not in" twice. Thanks Pavel.

Answer (score 1):

Using `NOT EXISTS` will also take care of the `NULL` problem with using `IN`

```
SELECT pictureid, id, points
FROM questions q
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT questions_id
    FROM history h
    WHERE h.questions_id = q.questions_id
    AND h.users_id = 3
)
```

If you want to use IN do this

```
SELECT pictureid, id, points
FROM questions q
WHERE q.id NOT IN
(
    SELECT questions_id
    FROM history h
    WHERE h.users_id = 3
    AND questions_id IS NOT NULL
)
```